# Android gallery custom view

Tags: android, view, background, gallery

I am using a custom view instead of a resource in my gallery. However the background of selected view is becoming black. The code for getView in the baseadapter is like this:-

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyView grpView = new MyView(context);
        grpView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(105,105));
        grpView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        grpView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return grpView;
    }
```

I want the selected view to be nicely framed like it happens when you use a xml resource like in API documentation:-

```
        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by

1. Drawing the background color in OnDraw of MyView. This removed the black background.
2. Again drew a light grey border for only selected view in OnDraw of MyView. This gave a similar effect to what happens with an xml resource.